# how to combine time periods in a string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string

Let say my input is like this

```
let s = "06:00 - 10:00, 10:00 - 14:00, 14:00 - 18:00, 22:00 - 02:00, 02:00 - 06:00";
```

I need to combine it like 
return `"06:00 - 18:00, 22:00 - 06:00"`

How can I combine it?
Thanks for helping.

Comment: What do you mean by combine ? Concat ? Moreover what is the rule for this concatenation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const input = '06:00 - 10:00, 10:00 - 14:00, 14:00 - 18:00, 22:00 - 02:00, 02:00 - 06:00';

const result = input
    .split(',')
    .map(str => str.replace(/\s/g, ''))
    .map(str => str.split('-'))
    .reduce((acc, val) => {
        if (acc.length === 0) {
            acc.push(val);
        } else {
            const prev = acc[acc.length - 1];

            if (prev[1] === val[0]) {
                prev[1] = val[1];
            } else {
                acc.push(val);
            }
        }

        return acc;
    }, [])
    .map(arr => arr.join(' - '))
    .join(', ');
    
console.log(result);
```

Comment: split with `' - '`. no need of `map(str => str.replace(/\s/g, ''))`

Comment: @User863 True, but I tried to handle as specific cases like: " 06:00- 10:00" :)

Comment: But that is not specified. Anyway you can use regex in split `str.split(/\s*-\s*/)`.